# Batch renaming files in OSX terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to rename files e.g. `screen-0001.tif` to `0001.tif` using the approach in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394112/how-can-i-batch-rename-files-using-the-terminal):

```
for file in *.tif
do
  echo mv "$file" "${screen-/file}"
done
```

fails to change anything. Grateful for an idea where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You are `echo`ing it, not performing the command itself. Also, you'd better use `${file/screen-/}` to delete the initial "screen-" text.

Comment: Cheers. Put that as the answer Mat I'll vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You're echoing the commands and not actually executing them. I will do this when I do massive renames just to make sure that the command works correctly. I can redirect the output to a file, and then use that file as a shell script.
2. The substitution is wrong. There are two ways:

   1. Left most filter `${file#screen-}`.
   2. Substitution: `${file/screen/}`

The name of the environment variable always goes first. Then the *pattern type*, then the pattern

Here's how I would do this:

```
$ for file in *.tif
> do
>   echo "mv '$file' '${file#screen-}'"
> done | tee mymove.sh   # Build a shell script 
$ vi mymove.sh           # Examine the shell script and make sure everything is correct
$ bash mymove.sh         # If all is good, execute the shell script.
```

Answer (score 3):

The easier, IMHO, way to do this is using Perl's `rename` script. Here I am using it with `--dry-run` so it just tells you what it would do, rather than actually doing anything. You would just remove `--dry-run` if/when you are happy with the command:

```
rename --dry-run 's/screen-//' *tif

'screen-001.tif' would be renamed to '001.tif'
'screen-002.tif' would be renamed to '002.tif'
'screen-003.tif' would be renamed to '003.tif'
'screen-004.tif' would be renamed to '004.tif'
```

It has the added benefit that it will not overwrite any files that happen to come out to the same name. So, if you had files:

```
screen-001.tif
0screen-01.tif
```

And you did this, you would get:

```
rename 's/screen-//' *tif
'screen-001.tif' not renamed: '001.tif' already exists
```

`rename` is easily installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), using:

```
brew install rename
```