# What script can I use to fix OneDrive for Business file syncing on a Mac

Tags: macos, sed, onedrive

We have OneDrive for Business (ODfB) on our Macs as a backup solution. ODfB has certain restrictions including files and folders not containing certain characters (including #/:%<>|"?*). What would be the best script to use to remove these characters from file and folder names? Perhaps sed? I only want the names of the files/folders changed not the content. Many thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37609516/2836621

Comment: Nice article but would prefer a Mac OS native command rather than the Perl rename. Thanks, though