# osx terminal: renaming files by hierarchy

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, rename, flatten

in OSX Terminal, I try to flatten a folder hierarchy, but as the files inside are named identical, I want to extend the filenames with its former folder names:

I'd like to get from here:

```
/dirA1/dirB1/file1.ext
/dirA1/dirB2/file1.ext
...
/dirA2/dirB1/file1.ext
...
```

to

```
/file1-dirA1-dirB1.ext
/file1-dirA1-dirB2.ext
...
/file1-dirA2-dirB1.ext
...
```

I've tried to combine renaming ([Batch renaming files in OSX terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253092)) with flattening (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52814) but no luck yet ...

Would I start with "find"? But how can I pass the directory names to "mv"?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A safe, but not very fast way would be to use `find` with `-exec`, passing each file to a shell command where you perform the replacements, like this:

```
(cd /path; find . -type f -exec sh -c 'newname=${1:2}; filename=${newname##*/}; dirname=${newname%/*}; newname=$filename-${dirname//\//-}; echo mv "$1" "$newname"' -- {} \;)
```

The reason for the `cd /path` instead of `find /path` is to so that we can work with relative paths from that base directory, which makes it easier to create the flattened file names.

A bit more explanation of the elements:

- `-exec sh -c '...' -- {}` executes `sh`, running the commands specified in `-c '...'`. The `{}` is the path found by `find`. The `-- ...` syntax is to pass parameters to the script as positional arguments, accessible via `$1`, `$2`, and so on.
- `newname=${1:2}` takes `$1`, the first positional argument, and extracts a sub-string from it, skipping the first two characters. I do this because the output of `find .` will have paths starting with `./`, and we want to remove that before replacing the `/` with `-`.
- `filename=${newname##*/}` extracts the filename part of the path, by removing everything from the beginning until the last `/`
- `dirname=${newname%/*}` extracts the directory name part of the path, by removing the last `/` and everything after it
- `${dirname//\//-}` replaces all occurrences of `/` with `-`. If you want to remove the `/` instead of replacing, then you can write `${dirname//\//}`

This technique is safe, because it will work with any special characters in filenames. It's slow because it runs `sh` for each file.

After this step the empty directories of the original files will remain, and you probably want to remove them:

```
find /path -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try asap. – Could you enlighten me (or point me to) what the newname=${1:2} and the newname//\/- each exactly do?

Comment: I added more explanation, and fixed an important typo. The replacement should be `newname=${newname//\//-}`, and not `newname=${newname//\/-}` as it was before my edit.

Comment: Thanks, Janos!   Actually, I'd like the directory names appended /after/ the original filename. How to I tell the mv to append the arguments instead of prepending them?   (Also, how could I completely remove the / character instead of replacing it with a -? I can't replace with a "no character", right?)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely handle this without executing `sh` for every file by feeding `find … -print0` output to a `while read` loop, like:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' old; do            # read filenames into $old
                                            # -d ''  : read until \0
                                            # -r     : no backslash escapes
                                            # IFS=   : no trimming whitespace
    if [[ $old =~ (.*)/(.*)\.(.*) ]]; then  # regex with capture groups:
       #           1    2     3
       set -- "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
       mv "$old" "${2}-${1//\/}.${3}"
    fi
done < <(find . -type f -print 0)
```

<sup>The purpose of the `set -- "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"` above is just to move the members of the array that contains regex match groups into the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc) for legibility.</sup>