# How to Batch Rename Files in a macOS Terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, file-rename

I have a folder with a series of files named:

```
prefix_1234_567.png
prefix_abcd_efg.png
```

I'd like to *batch remove* one underscore and the middle content so the output would be:

```
prefix_567.png
prefix_efg.png
```

Relevant but not completely explanatory:

- [How can I batch rename files using the Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394112)
- [Regex to batch rename files in OS X Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664542)

Comment: look at NSString and NSMutableString's range and substring methods

Comment: Have you considered non-terminal solutions to this? An Automator workflow can perform these types of operations with ease.

You could create an automator workflow to rename all of the files and replace the text with `_*_` with a blank.

Comment: i thought automator couldn't do wildcards

Answer (score 271, accepted):

In your specific case you can use the following `bash` command (`bash` is the default shell on macOS):

```
for f in *.png; do echo mv "$f" "${f/_*_/_}"; done
```

<sup>Note: If there's a chance that your filenames start with `-`, place `--`  before them[1]:

`mv -- "$f" "${f/_*_/_}"`</sup>

**Note: `echo` is prepended to `mv` so as to perform a dry run. Remove it to perform actual renaming.**

You can run it from the command line or use it in a script.

- `"${f/_*_/_}"` is an application of `bash` [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): the (first) substring matching pattern `_*_` is replaced with literal `_`, effectively cutting the middle token from the name.
- Note that `_*_` is a *pattern* (a wildcard expression, as also used for globbing), not a *regular expression* (to learn about patterns, run `man bash` and search for `Pattern Matching`).

---

If you find yourself batch-renaming files frequently, **consider installing a specialized tool such as the Perl-based [`rename` utility](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/)**.
On macOS you can install it using popular package manager [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) as follows:

```
brew install rename
```

Here's the equivalent of the command at the top using `rename`:

```
rename -n -e 's/_.*_/_/'  *.png
```

Again, this command performs a dry run; remove `-n` to perform actual renaming.

- Similar to the `bash` solution, `s/.../.../` performs text substitution, but - unlike in `bash` - true *regular expressions* are used.

---

<sup>[1] The purpose of special argument `--`, which is supported by most utilities, is to signal that subsequent arguments should be treated as *operands* (values), even if they *look* like *options* due to starting with `-`, as [Jacob C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8067821/jacob-c) notes.</sup>

Comment: great answer, worked perfectly. i also appreciate that you went back and edited it to explain it more and provide a more elegant solution if i repeat this. again, much thanks, very helpful

Comment: An example using matched replacements (`.*` -> `$1`), e.g. Rename `Foo bar S01E01 biz baz.ext` to `S01E01.ext`: `rename -n -e 's/.*(S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2}).*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/$1$2/' *`

Comment: Love the idea of using `echo` for dry runs. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Highly recommend just doing the `brew install rename`

Comment: Google and SO still give better answers sometimes

Answer (score 125):

To rename files, you can use the `rename` utility:

`brew install rename`

For example, to change a search string in all filenames in current directory:

```
rename -nvs searchword replaceword *
```

Remove the 'n' parameter to apply the changes.

More info: `man rename`

Comment: `OS X` versions of `GNU bash` (*x86_64-apple-darwin*) doesn't include the rename utility.

Comment: Thanks, yes it needs to be installed via `brew install rename`

Comment: This tip is awesome! I typed `rename -vs GLYCOPHORIN GLYCC *` and now it's automatically renaming 450+ files. And super fast too.

Comment: Excellent! Love the "show what would be changed" part BEFORe it actually renames things!

Comment: You can use a regex as well.  rename 's/123/onetwothree/g' *

Comment: If you like to replace any matched string use `S` parameter instead of `s`. If you like to use regex note: 1-regex is Perl-style  2-remove 's' parameter as this (`rename -nv 's/ /_/g' *`).

Comment: recoursive rename: rename -vs searchword replaceword **/*

Answer (score 18):

You could use sed:

```
ls * | sed -e 'p;s@_.*_@_@g' | xargs -n2 mv
```

result:

```
prefix_567.png prefix_efg.png
```

*to do a dry-run first, replace `mv` at the end with `echo`

Explanation:

- e: optional for only 1 sed command.
- p: to print the input to sed, in this case it will be the original file name before any renaming
- @: is a replacement of / character to make sed more readable. That is, instead of using sed s/search/replace/g, use s@search@replace@g
- _.* : the underscore is an escape character to refer to the actual '.' character zero or more times (as opposed to ANY character in regex)
- -n2:  indicates that there are 2 outputs that need to be passed on to mv as parameters. for each input from *ls*, this sed command will generate 2 output, which will then supplied to mv.

Comment: Clever, if somewhat arcane solution. Making this more general, so as to also support filenames with embedded spaces, gets even more arcane: `ls * | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo mv "%" "$(sed 's@_.*_@_@' <<<"%")"'` (remove `echo` to actually rename).

Comment: I found this useful for renaming and moving files that were named with `\ ` characters (they should have been `/`, and frankly, in those directories instead of with descriptive names).
For anyone looking for something so esoteric, it looks like `ls * | sed -e 'p;s@\\@\\\\\\\\@g' | xargs -n1 echo | sed -e 'p;s@\\\\@@g' | xargs -pn2 mv`, where `-p` displays the command to execute and asks for confirmation (`y` to confirm).

Answer (score 9):

I had a batch of files that looked like this: be90-01.png and needed to change the dash to underscore. I used this, which worked well:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | tr '-' '_'`"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

you can install `rename` command by using `brew`. just do `brew install rename` and use it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `mmv`

```
mmv '*_*_*' '#1_#3' *.png
```

Comment: Given this was OS X, the correct installation procedure is `brew install mmv`.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
for i in *.png ; do mv "$i" "${i/remove_me*.png/.png}" ; done
```

Here is another way:

```
for file in Name*.png; do mv "$file" "01_$file"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Since programmatically renaming files is risky (potentially destructive if you get it wrong), I would use a tool with a dry run mode built specifically for bulk renaming, e.g. [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer).

This command operates on all files in the current directory, use `--dry-run` until you're confident the output looks correct:

```
$ renamer --find "/(prefix_)(\w+_)(\w+)/" --replace "$1$3" -e name --dry-run *

Dry run

✔︎ prefix_1234_567.png → prefix_567.png
✔︎ prefix_abcd_efg.png → prefix_efg.png

Rename complete: 2 of 2 files renamed.
```

Plenty more renamer usage examples [here](https://github.com/75lb/renamer/wiki/Examples).

Answer (score 1):

`zsh` is now the default shell for macOS and it has its own bulk renaming feature, `zmv` which is sometimes aliased as `mmv` to `noglob zmv -W`.