# How can I batch change the first part of a group of files' names in Terminal (EDIT: OS X)?

Tags: macos, terminal, rename, batch-processing

I have a group of files with a set prefix, and I would like to change that prefix on all of the files simultaneously in terminal. So let's say I wanted to change this group

```
01-here.md
01-is.md
01-an.md
01-example.md
```

to this

```
02-here.md
02-is.md
02-an.md
02-example.md
```

I'm looking for something along the lines of `mv 01*.md 02*.md`, but that doesn't work. After digging around a bit I found an easy way to accomplish the same task using finder, but finder is for slowpokes and losers, obviously, so I still want to know how to do it "for realz."

EDIT: Using OS X

Comment: You didn't state what OS and what shell you are using.

Comment: He said "in Terminal" and not "in _the_ terminal," (and he also mentioned Finder) so I'm assuming it's OSX. Ordinarily, the [batch-file] tag would mean this question is exclusively for Windows, but people confuse it with the [batch-processing] tag way more than they should.

Comment: Correct on both counts, @SomethingDark. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a script called `rename` for this, but if I didn't, I would use a loop, something like this:

```
for f in 01-*.md; do mv "$f" "${f/01/02}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (edited answer):

```
INITIAL_SUFFIX="01-";
FINAL_SUFFIX="02-";

for file in $(ls -1 "$INITIAL_SUFFIX"*); do
        if [ -f $file ]; then
                mv $file "$FINAL_SUFFIX${file#*-}";
        fi;
done
```

Comment: Not quite. This renames all files and folders in the working directory, regardless of whether or not they share a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

For your example situation, try

```
for f in *.md; do echo mv "$f" "${f/2/3}"; done
```

(Note: the echo will just show you what will happen, remove it to actually rename files). A good explanation of this excerpt can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102974/mac-os-x-terminal-batch-rename).

On another note, you could do this in Applescript or Automater too, both of which offer a solid amount of functionality for batch renaming and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, most flexible way to do this is with the Perl `rename` script. On OSX, it can easily be installed with `homebrew`, using

```
brew install rename
```

Then you can do:

```
rename 's/01/02/' *md
```

If you want to just see what it would do, without actually doing anything, use the `--dry-run` option as follows:

```
rename --dry-run 's/01/02/' 01*md
```

**Output**

```
'01-an.md' would be renamed to '02-an.md'
'01-example.md' would be renamed to '02-example.md'
'01-here.md' would be renamed to '02-here.md'
'01-is.md' would be renamed to '02-is.md'
```

It also will not overwrite any files if they work out to the same resulting filename and can do **much, much** more sophisticated renaming.