# rename all png files in multiple directory

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I have multiple png files in multiple directory, I want to rename all of them to Info.png 

 for example:
`Projects\p1\Screen-1298.png
Projects\s4\Screen-43.png
Projects\k21\Screen-456.png
Projects\p14\Screen-345.png`
To
`Projects\p1\Info.png
Projects\s4\Info.png
Projects\k21\Info.png
Projects\p14\Info.png`

Is there a single command to do that instead of renaming each file individually?

Comment: 8 files - 30 secs per file - 4minutes work - Why post the question?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of half of these search results for ["batch rename osx"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+rename+osx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with `find ~/Projects -type f -name '*.png' -execdir mv {} Info.png \;`

Answer (score 0):

The premise of this question seems flawed because it assumes that one either has to use a single command or do everything manually when, in fact, there are other options. E.g. is a perl based script a single command? If you believe it is, then `brew install rename` and use that as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102974/mac-os-x-terminal-batch-rename). Otherwise, use the one-liner suggested by @Gregory Pakosz or check out these [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+rename+osx).