# OS X file rename

Tags: bash, macos, file, shell, file-rename

I have PDFs with the following name pattern:

```
ABC12345V1_6789_V0-1_xyz.pdf
ABC12345V4_6789_V3-7_xyz.pdf
```

Important parts are **V#** and **V#-#**. Whatever is the number after the first **V** the number after the second **V** is always one less. I'd like to create a service that renames the above pattern to these:

```
ABC12345V1_6789_V1_xyz.pdf
ABC12345V4_6789_V4_xyz.pdf
```

Basically the **V#-#** part needs to be identical to the first **V#** in the filename. There may be other letter Vs somewhere in the filename.

I found [mac os x terminal batch rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102974/mac-os-x-terminal-batch-rename) useful but I'd need to assign the new value to the string to be replaced.

Comment: Do you have `GNU coreutils` installed?

Comment: No, I don't have yet. Searching through previous questions I was thinking maybe [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew) is something that can solve this?

Comment: `brew install rename` ... and `rename --help` looks promising. Given the `brew info` knowledge, "this" is the Perl-powered file rename script [...] bottled from http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename . HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regex to accomplish this:

```
r=$"V([0-9])_([0-9]*)_V";

for f in *.pdf; do
    if [[ $f =~ $r ]]; then
        mv "$f" "${f/_*_/_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_V${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_}";
    fi
done
```

Result:

```
ABC12345V1_6789_V0-1_xyz.pdf ABC12345V1_6789_V1_xyz.pdf
ABC12345V4_6789_V3-7_xyz.pdf ABC12345V4_6789_V4_xyz.pdf
```

Comment: Any reason for an i18n string `$"..."`?

Comment: @andlrc: It's just a habit; it should work with or without `$`; all good on shellcheck.net :)

Comment: This has an extra **V** at the end, which prevented running `r=$"V([0-9])_([0-9]*)_V";` once it's removed it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This script works fine on OS X without GNU coreutils.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.pdf
do
    _fs=$(echo "$f" |grep -o "V[0-9]_")
    newfile=$(echo "$f" | awk -F"V[0-9][^_]*_" -v fs=$_fs '{print $1fs$2fs$3}')
    mv -v "$f" "$newfile"
done
```

Just copy the content above to `rename.sh`, and `chmod u+x rename.sh`, it will rename all your files in current directory.

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release

$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

$ awk --version
awk version 20070501
```

Comment: It's almost fine but the **V#_** is placed at the end of the filename:

`ABC12345V1_6789_V0-1_xyz.pdf ABC12345V1_6789_V0-1_xyz.pdfV1_`