# How to rename multiple files by truncating the name with command line?

Tags: terminal

*2001.png
2002.png
2003.png
2004.png
2005.png
2006.png*

Let's say I want to programmatically rename these pics to be called:

*1.png
2.png
3.png
4.png
5.png
6.png*

Best way to do this with terminal? Does it involve Regex? In this case I would assume so since I'm truncating letters

Comment: When you say "terminal", do you mean "shell"? Which one? Did you try something? "Best way" is actually almost opinion based. It'd be useful if you showed what you tried. Is it always the first three characters you want to remove? Are they always exactly `200`?

Comment: Thank you for responding to my first stackoverflow post.

Yes I mean shell. Yes I tried something--searched stackoverflow for a solution. Yes in this small use case, it's truncating 200 everytime.

This post was semi-relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102974/mac-os-x-terminal-batch-rename

Comment: You should [edit] the question to update it with that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the files in the current directory and change change their names by using move command. In this case, you want to take substring of the name from 3rd character(after 3rd characters 5 symbols are remaining, so take 5 characters starting with 3rd -  **file:3:5**).

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.png; do
    new_file=${file:3:5}
    mv "$file" "${new_file%}"
done
```

Comment: Is the `%` a typo? It doesn't hurt, but it also doesn't do anything (it removes the empty string from the end of `new_file`).