# Renaming Files Using Bash Python or Linux Command

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a directory with files, whose names I need to standardize.

The names like `audio_32.mp4.mp4` I would like to change to `audio_0-32.mp4`. That is, I would like to add a zero after the underscore and introduce a hyphen afterwards. The files differ by the number in their name. That is, there will also be a file named `audio_33.mp4.mp4` and so on. I would like to leave all other files and patterns unchanged. It is fine if removing the tail `.mp4` and adding the zero are dealt with as separate tasks.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: I'd use `rename`, a.k.a. Perl rename https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720198/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in pure bash:

```bash
for f in *.mp4; do
   t="${f%.mp4}"
   echo mv "$f" "${t/_/_0-}"
done
```

Once you're satisfied with the output, remove `echo` before `mv` to rename your files instead of printing `mv` command.

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system will your code be run on? There are already a lot of tools for this sort of thing that exist, so you're entering re-invent the wheel territory here.

Powertoys PowerRename for example is designed for exactly this.

That said, if I assume the availability of the typical GNU toolset you can get rid of the mp4 with "basename":

```
[user@host]$ basename audio_33.mp4.mp4 .mp4
audio_33.mp4
[user@host]$
```

The rest you can do with basic string manipulation:

```
[user@host]$ X=audio_33.mp4
[user@host]$ echo ${X/audio_/audio_0-}
audio_0-33.mp4
[user@host]$
```